# How to evaluate if the cardinality of LHS = RHS

Tags: database

I found the following question from this site

https://www.facebook.com/visiesoft/posts/829466197145968

Given two relation R1(a1, a2, a3) with N1 tuples and R2(b1, b2, a1) with N2 tuples. We suppose that a1 in R2 is a foreign key referencing a1in R1. Explain when each of the following cases is possible (Card means cardinality – the number of elements)

1. Card(πa1(R1)) = Card(R1) is true since the number of records are the same, and a1 is primary and it cannot be null, then the statement is true.
2. Card(πa1(R1)) = Card(πa1(R2)) since a1 is primary key in R1 and a1 is FK in R2 from R1, and if we say that it has 1 to 1 relation with full participation then the statement is true.
3. Card(πa1(R1)) > Card(R1) This cannot be true since they perform in R1 and a1 is PK and it must have the same number records.
4. Card(σa1=10(R1) = 0 this statement can be true if a1 does not hold value 10.
5. Card(σa1=10(R1) > Card(R1) This also cannot be true.

I solved some cases, but the other cases are not realistic for me since it takes a subset from relation R1 and says it is larger than the whole relation.

How can this be possible?